# Walletconnect integration not working on mobile

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, ethereumjs, walletconnect

This is a weird one. I have successfully integrated walletconnect on my Dapp for the first time and it works just fine on my pc. When I try accessing it on my phone, it doesn't work. I am trying a clone of pinksale for practice here: https://www.pinksale.is/launchpad/0xD768a3bF5F24f7C3150D68326488C5c0208115Ee?chain=BSC

everything works just fine on my computer but nothing works on my phone and I can't seem to figure out why.

I am supposed to be able to click on connect and select "Connect to WalletConnect" and that should popup the walletconnect qrcode and option, but it doesn't work on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mobile WalletConnect tries to default to deeplinking instead of QR codes.

If everything is properly integrated you will see a screen like this
[image]

There you can also switch to the QR code.

Comment: I know this, the problem is that it is working well on my desktop but nothing shows on mobile.

Did you try to replicate this issue with the link above? https://www.pinksale.is/launchpad/0xD768a3bF5F24f7C3150D68326488C5c0208115Ee?chain=BSC

Visit this link on pc and mobile and see what I mean, thank you

Comment: Ahh you are correct, it seems that the implementation of this side relies on MetaMask being present. If I open the website on desktop into a private tab without MetaMask it is also not working :/ ... but there is no error log, so hard to say without looking into the source.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "Mobile Linking" the process is cover here .
https://docs.walletconnect.com/mobile-linking